# When i update an android app i am getting error code:-26.How to solve it?

Tags: android

When i update an android app i am getting  error code:-26.How to solve it?[image]

Comment: I am voting to close this as it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check whether you have ticked "App Permissions" ON under settings ?

Settings->Security->App permission

If you have turned it on, you might run into such issues. Please turn it off for updating the app.

I hope this would solve the issue.